# Clarification of terms with reference to weight function of Orthogonal Polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, orthogonality

I am looking at "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables" by Abramowitz and Stegen. In particular I am looking at the beginning of Chapter 22: Orthogonal Polynomials. It says

> A system of polynomials $f_n(x)$, degree $[f_n(x)] = n$, is called orthogonal on the interval $a \leq x \leq b$, with repect to the weight function $w(x)$ if
> \begin{equation}
> \int_a^b w(x) f_n(x)f_m(x) dx =0 \quad (n,m=0,1,2 \ldots; n \neq m)
> \end{equation}
> **The weight function $w(x)[w(x) \geq 0]$ determines the system $f_n(x)$ up to a constant factor in each polynomial. The specification of these factors is referred to as standardization**. For suitably  standardized orthogonal polynomials we set
> \begin{equation}
> \int_a^b w(x) f^2_n(x) dx = h_n
> \end{equation}

I have two questions relating to this. Firstly, according to *Wolfram MathWorld*, the $h_n$ in the equation above is the normalisation constant. I'm not fully sure what this means. A normalization constant for a vector makes its magnitude $1$. What does it mean for a polynomial to be normalized? Does it mean that if you divide all the $f_n(x)$ by $h_n(x)$, you obtain an orthonormal system?

Secondly, I am confused at what the part of the passage I have in bold. Is the first sentence saying that the weight function is a constant multiple of each polynomial is the system or something else? In the second sentence, I don't know what "the specification of these factors" means.

Note: Later in the chapter, the authors provide the "Standardizations" for some polynomials. The ones for the Gegenabuer polynomials are

> \begin{align}
> C^{(\alpha)}_n(1) &= \binom{n+2\nu-1}{n} \quad (\alpha \neq 0), \\
> C^{(0)}_n(1) &= \frac{2}{n}, \\
> C^{(0)}_0(1) &= 1. 
> \end{align}

I happen to know that $C^{(\alpha)}_n(1)$ is actually the maximum value that the Gegenbauer polynomials can obtain on the interval $[-1, 1]$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
|C^{(\alpha)}_n(x)| \leq C^{(\alpha)}_n(1), \qquad \forall x \in [-1, 1]. 
\end{equation}
Is this related to what the standardization is?

Any clarity on what these terms mean would be great!

Comment: You seem to think $h_n$ is a polynomial: it's not, it's a constant, and in fact a positive constant. So it makes perfect sense to to normalise by replacing $f_n(x)$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{h_n}} f_n(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, think of $\int_a^b wfg$ as a scalar product on $\mathbb{R}[X]$ If you read again, you'll notice that $h_n$ is a constant, not a polynomial, indeed, $h_n = \|f_n \|^2$ for this euclidian norm. That is why (as you almost have written) $(\frac{1}{h_n} f_n)_n$ is an orthonormal basis of your euclidian vector space.

For the second question, it only means that assuming that $\deg f_n= n$ and $(f_i)$ orthogonal for this scalar product is sufficient to determine successively $f_1, f_2, \dots$ up to scalar multiplication. For example you can do a gram-schmidt method. The thing is that if you don't require $\|f_i \| = 1$ and that the first coefficient of $f_i$ is positive, you won't have unicity, so for example both $f_i$ and $2 f_i$ are suitable candidates, and for each $i$, the set of suitable candidates for $f_i$ is $\{\lambda f_i, \lambda \neq 0\}$.

For you standardisation, the author uses a particular technique, since Gegenbauer's polynomial satisfying orthogonality for some weight function are not identically $0$ on $[-1,1]$, you can fix the $\lambda$ desired for each $i$ by imposing this linear constraint on these polynomials.

Comment: I am not sure I fully follow the arguments. I will put each question regarding my confusion in its own comment. If $\int_a^b wfg = <f,g>$ as you say then $\int_a^b w f^2 = <f, f> = ||f||^2 = h_n$. But why is the $w$ not involved in the inner product? Should it not be $\int_a^b wfg = <wf,g>$ or something like that. Also, this is the $L^2$ inner product, not the Euclidian inner product, right?

Comment: If you denote $\langle f,g\rangle_2 = \int_a^b f g$ the canonical euclidian inner product, you indeed have $\langle wf,g\rangle_2 = \int_a^b wf g$, but you can define a new euclidian inner product from the old one: $$\langle f,g\rangle_w = \int_a^b w f g = \langle wf,g\rangle_2$$

Comment: OK, so in the second question. Am I correct in saying the following. If $f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots$ are a system of polynomials which are orthogonal with respect to the weight function $w(x)$, then 1. $\int_a^b w(x) f_i f_j =0$. 2. We also have that $\lambda_1 f_1, \lambda_2 f_2, \lambda_3 f_3, \ldots$ are also orthogonal in the same way. That is, constant multiple of a function also is orthogonal and these constants can be different for each function.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the standardization given for the Gegenbauer polynomials in fact imposes that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = \ldots$. Does this have something to do with the fact that the standardization is the maximum attainable value on the interval of integration. This is my last question.

Comment: yes for the second question and yes for the last (maybe up to a sign)

Comment: Brilliant. One small remaining question. My original motivation for trying to understand this was to figure out why the maximum of the Gegenbauer polynomials was given by $C_{n}^{(\alpha)}(1)$ and where it comes from. Do you have inclination of the "technique" the author uses to obtain the standardization and how it might relate to the maximum value of the polynomials. Would it be correct to say that it comes directly from the orthogonality relation or is it just a coincidence that the maximum value is the value which imposes all the $\lambda_i$ be equal.

Comment: I think the author (and the mathematical world) chose these values because Gegenbauer's polynomials are "generalizations" of Legendre polynomials, which are heavily linked with binomials, however I am not sure about it, there are probably very good reasons to make these choices. It also has links with Tchebychev's polynomials which are also linked with binomials, but maybe does the author give a little bit of explanation?

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very helpful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials

Comment: No pb :) good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, the author just states that the standardization is as I have written above and then much later states that $C_n^{(\alpha)}(x) \leq C_n^{(\alpha)}(1)$ in a section titled "Inequalities". If he does provide justification for these results, I can't find them!